# Change splash screen on GRUB 0.97

Tags: linux, boot, grub, graphics

I'm running a Linux from SuseStudio. I would like to change the background image at the GRUB screen. menu.lst contains the line `gfxmenu (hd0,0)/boot/message`. When I `strings` the file, I see the line `background=pback.jpg`. I replaced the file (found in /usr/share/gfxboot/themes/studio/data-boot), but the boot image is still the old one. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

For GRUB 0.97, I'm pretty sure of two things:

1. All splash images must be compressed xpm's (*.xpm.gz).  Only GRUB 2 allows you to use jpegs.
2. The line to use is something like this:

   splashimage=(hd0,1)/boot/grub/splashimages/mygrubsplash.xpm.gz

Since it looks like you're using **gfx**, that changes things.  Take a look at your gfxboot.cfg.  I think the pback.jpg is only valid for the "penguin" theme.  If you see a line that indicates "penguin=0", then it isn't using that theme and altering that file won't matter.

The default background image in gfx is "back.jpg", and its (somewhere) under the gfxboot directory structure.  Try replacing that file, and see if your background changes.

Also I'm not sure about gfx, but GRUB 0.97 has restrictions on the file size and resolution that you can use.  I think the recommended resolution for gfx is 800x600.